# How is the transactionId generated?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

In the blockchain, every transaction has a transactionId where does this come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TXID is the double sha256 hash of the signed transaction, used to uniquely identify a particular transaction.

When you create/sign a transaction that hash will be generated with your transaction.

Comment: So it's the digital signature? Is there a comprehensive website that I can use to read up on bitcoin? From a programmers point of view.

Comment: Yeah, There's a book called Mastering Bitcoin by Andreas Antonopoulos , Best book ever.

Comment: If TxId is the hash of the transaction data, how it is made unique to guard against fraudulent duplicate transactions (including timestamp)?

Comment: @HiranmayGhosh: The output of cryptographic hash functions is collision resistant and 2^256 is a huge space of numbers.

Comment: It is the *double* sha256.

Answer (score 0):

The TXID is the hash of the transaction.